# How to avoid Android soft keyboard pushing Camera GLSurfaceView up?

Tags: android, android-layout, camera, android-edittext, glsurfaceview

I open the Camera with `GLSurfaceView`. What's more, there is `EditText` in the Layout. The layout maybe like this:

```
<com.example.widget.AspectFrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/cameraPreview_afl"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" >

    <android.opengl.GLSurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/glsurfaceView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
</com.example.widget.AspectFrameLayout>
<EditText
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

The problem is when i input something into the EditText, the soft keybord will be active and push the camera preview up.

How to avoid soft keyboard pushing Camera preview up when trigger the `EditText` ?

Comment: Hi @fadden, do you have any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In the GLSurfaceView constructor, you need to add these :

```
this.setFocusable(true);
this.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
```

And next show the keyboard:

```
((InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).showSoftInput(view, 0);
```

Comment: It seems can't work. What's the view, is it EditText?

Comment: This is the reference link I have got these informations :

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=860488

Comment: Thanks for you link. When invoke `((InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).showSoftInput(view, 0);` ? Maybe i missed something. Invoking `showSoftInput ` in a wrong place.